# What is the probability of a 50% free throw basketball shooter getting variations of 3 buckets in a row?

Tags: probability

Suppose someone is a 50% basketball freethrow shooter.  I allow them to properly "warm up" (practice), then I give that person 20 shots and want to know the following :

**Variation A**. What is the probability this person will make exactly 3 buckets in a row only once in that 20 shot round?

B = Bucket, M = Miss

example: MMBM MBMM BMMM BBBM BMBM  (spaces for easier readability only).

**Variation B**.  What is the probability this person will make at least 3 buckets in a row only once in that 20 shot round, that is, only one string of those?

I just realized that this one is basically asking what is the probability of getting between 3 and 5 in a row, but only once total.  6 in a row would not count because that would be interpreted as 2 strings of 3 in a row.

example: MMBM MBMM BMMM BBBB BMBM  (5 in a row but only 1 occurrence of that)

**Variation C**.  What is the probability this person will make 3 buckets in a row more than once in the same 20 shot round?

example: MMBM MBMM BMMM BBBB BBMM

Note in this one, what appears to be a string of 6 buckets is actually interpreted as 2 strings of non-overlapping 3 bucket events.  The strings of 3 buckets can have misses in between them.  This one is a special variation in that we allow consecutive occurrences of 3 in a row to count as multiple occurrences of 3 in a row, rather than 6, 9, 12... in a row.  That way we don't have to "force" at least one miss in between each 3 buckets.

Assumptions are the shooter makes an honest attempt to make all shots and whenever he makes or misses, it doesn't affect his free throw % which stays at 50%.

Which of these 3 variations is the hardest to solve?  How do I go about setting these up?

Comment: What about 4 buckets in a row? Is that interpreted as two overlapping strings of 3 buckets for part C?

Comment: There was 1 more variation I left out purposely which is at least 3 buckets in a row but more than once in the 20 shot round.  For example, MBBBBMBBBBBMMMMMMMMM...  Here we have 2 strings  >3  buckets.  We don't have to solve this but it is just food for thought.

Comment: For part C they have to be completely nonoverlapping.  The example I gave had 6 in a row but it says it counts as 2 nonoverlapping strings of 3 buckets each.  Something like MBBBBM is NOT two overlapping strings of 3 buckets because they do indeed overlap.  It would have to be something like ...MBBBMBBBM... or ...MBBBBBBM....

Comment: And just to clarify, for part A shooting four in a row only once is counted? For example, MBBBBMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM?

Comment: No, that is 4 in a row.  The question is exactly 3 in a row and only once.  ...MBBBMM... is good, ...MBBBMMMBBBMM... is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Variation A only, the possible outcomes are:

BBBM then (max $2$-streak of B's among $16$ shots)

(max $2$-streak of B's among $16$ shots) then MBBB

(max $2$-streak of B's among $k$ shots) then MBBBM then (max $2$-streak of B's among $15-k$ shots) over $k = 0$ through $15$ inclusive

Which means if $F(n)$ represents the number of sequences of length $n$ with a max B-streak of $2$ or less, then the answer is $\frac{2F(16) + \sum_{k=0}^{15} F(k)F(15-k)}{2^{20}}$

The number of max $2$-streaks can follow a recurrence:

$F(0) = 1$ (empty seq)

$F(1) = 2$ (outcomes M, B)

$F(2) = 4$ (outcomes MM, MB, BM, BB)

$F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) + F(n-3)$

This allows quick computation of the result once you generate the $F$-values:

Python script:

```
F = [1, 2, 4]

for n in range(3, 16 + 1):
    F.append(F[n - 1] + F[n - 2] + F[n - 3])

print((2 * F[16] + sum(F[k] * F[15 - k] for k in range(16))) / 2**20)  # 0.2182178497314453
```

Comment: These kind of problems really make people think about patterns and how to do medium difficulty counting.  It is very cool how something like this can be expressed mathematically using a recurrence relation.  Glad to see our answers of about 21.82% match.  That is encouraging.

Comment: It seems that some problems like this are solved much easier on a computer simply by having it count them up.  This was greatly simplified by making the free throw (FT) % exactly 50%.  That way I could just generate all bitstrings ($0$s and $1$s) of length 20 (all 2^20 = 1,048,576 of them), and just look for the patterns I wanted.  If however the FT% was something else such as 60%, I would have to think harder how to do that.  I suppose I could generate a bunch of bitstrings with 60% bias towards buckets and then choose randomly from them to get an approximation, but not an exact answer.

Comment: Referencing the above comment, I suppose if I generated at least 2^20 random bitstrings with the 60% bias towards buckets, I could then use the same algorithm to find the desired patterns, changing only the data it operates on.  This could be as simple as generating a different database holding the 60% bias bitstrings.  I might even try it for fun.  It is pretty impressive when I just change the data instead of changing the algorithm and it still works properly.  Perhaps 2^20 random bitstrings is not really enough so maybe I can do 2^24 or something reasonable like that.  What is a good # ?

Comment: is there a general rule when using random bitstrings on length n to have some multiple of n to choose from for better "randomness" (such as 2^24 = 16 * (2^20)?  Should I check for at least 1 of each possible bitstring if I am storing them in a database to be used multiple times (for different pattern matching).

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer a computer simulation answer here for crosschecking of any mathematical solutions and perhaps to give people some ideas on how to count it mathematically.

Since the probability of making the bucket is the same as that of missing it (50/50), I just had my computer generate all binary bitstrings on length 20, store them into a database, then I reread them each time I want to count all occurrences of some condition.

**For part A**, I check for Occurs("111", bitstring20) = 1 which tells me that 111 occurs only once in that bitstring20 (nonoverlapping) which is not the final answer since we overcounted due to cases like 1111 and 11111. Case 111111 will NOT be counted since the Occurs("111", bitstring20) function will see that as a double non-overlapping occurrence and already not count it.  Since 1111 is a prefix of 11111, all occurrences of 11111 will also be picked up my the Occurs("1111", bitstring20) check.  So my full test for a "hit" (good event) is Occurs("111", bitstring20) = 1 and Occurs("1111", bitstring20) = 0.

I get an answer of 228,818 out of 1,048,576 which is about 21.82%.

**For part B**, Not sure if this is right but I just check for Occurrence of 111 to be exactly one.  That will not count any runs of 6 or more, but WILL count runs of 4 or 5 which are ok since runs of 4 or 5 are not double non-overlapping occurrences of runs of 3.

I get an answer of 407,167 out of 1,048,576 which is about 38.83%.

**For part C**, I simply check if the # of occurrences of 111 are at least 2.  So for example, if the first 6 are buckets (111111), then we are done.  That is a good event. 111000...111 is also a good event. 1 = bucket made.

I get an answer of 418,092 out of 1,048,576 which is about 39.87%.

Comment: I thought maybe I would get at least 1 upvote for a simple algorithm and one robust enough to even work with biased shooters (such as 60%, 40%...).  Hey at least I made an effort and seem to have gotten the right answers.